# When and why do I need to quote asterisks

Tags: linux, bash, wildcards

I don't think I ever fully grokked the rules of when and why one needs to doublequote things in Linux/Bash (I'm not sure if this problem's domain is Linux, Bash, or something else). I thought that `*` matched any number of characters (including none), and this seems to align with [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). But when I tried to use the `*` wildcard as follows, I got results I don't understand:

```
>pwd
/home/user/foo/foo/test
>tree 
.
├─ main.opp
└─ test
   └─ test.opp

>find ../ -name *.opp
../test/test.opp

>find ../ -name "*.opp"
../main.opp
../test/test.opp

>cd ..
>pwd
/home/user/foo/foo

>find . -name *.opp
./main.opp

>find . -name "*.opp"
./main.opp
./test/test.opp
```

Why does `find` with the non-doublequoted `*.opp` argument only return one hit, whereas doublequoting the same returns the expected two hits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends when the expansion is evaluated.
If you don't quote the asterisk, bash evaluates it first. It's equivalent to calling `find . -name main.opp`.
If you quote the asterisk, it's passed as-is to find which uses it the way you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Without quote, bash will expand the asterisk if there is any matching files in the current directory. Here I use `echo` to debug the expansion.

```
~/foo/foo/test$ echo find ../ -name *.oop
find ../ -name test.oop
~/foo/foo/test$ cd ..
~/foo/foo$ echo find . -name *.oop
find . -name main.oop
```

If you search for something which does **not give a match** in the current directory, it will not expand:

```
~/foo/foo$ echo find . -name test.*
find . -name test.*
~/foo/foo$ find . -name test.*
./test/test.oop
```